# preventing users to create my site

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, my-site, profile-sync

If you synchronize Users so it means that you have created a profile for everyone in Users and everybody in Users can create My Site if he/she logs on to a machine which is contected to AD. is it true? How do I prevent certain users to create My site?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to Central Admin -> Manage Service Applications -> User Profile Service Application

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Do I need to do it for all users that I want to prevent?

Comment: You can do it for all or a subset of users in an organization to be able/unable to create My Sites, so you enable the Create Personal Site permission for those users

Comment: I am newbie in this topic, please help me understand how do I create a organistaion. Is it a unit in AD or a AD group? thanks

Comment: You can create a group of Users in the AD.